# How to decide if a classifier is linear or not?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear

If the decision boundary of a binary classifier consists of multiple hyperplanes, is it still a linear classifier? If not, in multi-class classification, how do we define linear classifier? Can we still have linear classifier?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier

Answer (score 0):

If the decision boundary of a binary classifier can be represented as a linear sum (i.e. a single hyperplane), then it is linear.

In the multi-class case, there are two ways of defining a linear classifier:

1. **one-vs-rest** - For each class `A` in your multiclass output set, reframe your problem as `A` vs. `not-A`, and solve for a linear decision boundary. If you have `n` possible classes, you end up with `n - 1` linear decision boundaries. Then you use an argmax for the numerical outputs at the end to make a final decision.
2. **one-vs-rest** - Train a linear classifier between every possible pair of output labels. You end up with `n(n-1)/2` classifiers in this case. Based on which class was predicted the most, that is your final decision.

More reading on formulating multiclass problems linearly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification